# AWS CodeDeploy running util timeout then failing even though no erros

Tags: linux, bash, shell, aws-code-deploy, bitbucket-aws-code-deploy

I am running a CICD code deploy that is triggered via a Bitbucket pipeline. It all runs as expected, i.e. the code builds, deploys and the server starts perfectly with no errors.

**Problem**

However, the deployment will continue to run until it times out, and then will report the deployment as a failure. It is as if the `AfterInstall` call to the `deploy.sh` is ever released.

**Question**

What am I doing wrong?  What must I do to release the deployment to allow it to complete with the server running in the background?

Do I need to change the `deploy.sh`, i.e. it needs to end with a '&'.?

**Setup**

I have a CodeDeploy set up as follows:

**appspec.yml**

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: target/pow-wow-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
    destination: /home/jboss/bitbucket/pow-wow
    overwrite: true
file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/deploy.sh
      timeout: 300
```

**deploy.sh**

```
echo "about to deploy to pow-wow ($USER) ..."
export JAVA_HOME=/home/jboss/.sdkman/candidates/java/current
echo $JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
cd /home/jboss/bitbucket/pow-wow
pwd
if lsof -Pi :8080 -sTCP:LISTEN
then
    echo "pow-wow is running"
    echo "stopping pow-wow on port 8080 ..."
    kill -9 $(lsof -t -i tcp:8080)
else
    echo "pow-wow is not running"
fi
mv pow-wow-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar target/
cd /home/jboss/bitbucket/pow-wow/logs
if [ -e nohup.out ]
then
  echo "Sorting logs  ..."
  cat nohup.out >> nohup-$(date --iso).out
  echo "archive logs to nohup-date.out and remove nohup.out"
  rm nohup.out
fi
echo "starting pow-wow ..."
cd /home/jboss/bitbucket/pow-wow
nohup java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=uat target/pow-wow-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar > logs/nohup.out &
if [ -e logs/nohup.out ]
then
  echo "Created /home/jboss/bitbucket/pow-wow/logs/nohup.out"
fi
echo "Run Start pow-wow."
```